# Laravel Broadcast Event not firing

Tags: php, laravel, events, laravel-5

I am trying to broadcast an event every time a new market snapshot is created. I followed the laravel tutorial [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/broadcasting).

But it seems I am missing something since even the log is not being created:

```
    namespace App\Events;

    use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
    use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
    use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
    use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
    use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

    class NewMarketSnapshot implements ShouldBroadcast
    {
        use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

        /**
         * Create a new event instance.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function __construct()
        {
            //
        }

        /**
         * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
         *
         * @return Channel|array
         */
        public function broadcastOn()
        {
            \Log::info('event broadcasted');

            return new Channel('snapshot');
        }
    }
```

I even registered the event in EventServiceProvider (not mentioned on the laravel link)

```
protected $listen = [
    'App\Events\NewMarketSnapshot' => [
      'App\Listeners\NewMarketSnapshotListener',
    ],
];
```

The handler is being called but the event is not being broadcasted.

```
    namespace App\Listeners;

    use App\Events\NewMarketSnapshot;
    use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
    use \Log;

    class NewMarketSnapshotListener
    {
        /**
         * Create the event listener.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function __construct()
        {
            //
        }

        /**
         * Handle the event.
         *
         * @param  NewMarketSnapshot  $event
         * @return void
         */
        public function handle(NewMarketSnapshot $event)
        {
            Log::info('handler called.');
        }
    }
```

Testing with the simple route:

```
Route::get('/test', function(){
    $snapshot = ['USD'=>100];
    return event(new App\Events\NewMarketSnapshot($snapshot));
});
```

Lines in my .env file

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=redis
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=redis

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

Comment: and what broadcaster are you using ?pusher ?

Comment: Nope... using redis

Comment: Can you share your .`env` file? That may be helpful.

Comment: Just edited into the question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I note that you are using Redis as both the queue and broadcast driver. My experience has been that using it for both breaks the broadcasting (basically it sends the wrong command to Redis on the broadcast event).

If you switch the queue to a different driver or use separate Redis instances it should hopefully work OK.

EDIT: I believe under these circumstances it uses the Redis RPUSH command, when it should use PUBLISH instead, and as such the subscriber never picks it up.

EDIT2: Don't forget to clear any cached config with 
"php artisan config:clear"

Comment: Let me try switching to 'sync' for the queue driver.

Comment: @TechyTimo I don't recall exactly what the difference was, but if you run `redis-cli monitor` and then trigger the event with the two different config settings then if there's a difference you should see it there.

Comment: Although, bear in mind this was with Laravel 5.2 that I experienced it so it's not impossible that it's no longer an issue...

Comment: I am not quite sure I know what to do here. I tried switching queue driver to sync but i still cant see the broadcast event being fired.

Comment: Are you seeing any activity in the Redis monitor?

Comment: Yes -
1504957020.570157 [0 127.0.0.1:64271] "SELECT" "0"
1504957020.571288 [0 127.0.0.1:64271] "RPUSH" "queues:default" "{\"displayName\":\"App\\\\Events\\\\NewMarketSnapshot\",\"job\":\"Illuminate\\\\Queue\\\\CallQueuedHandler@call\",\"maxTries\":null,\"timeout\":null,\"data\":{\"commandName\":\"Illuminate\\\\Broadcasting\\\\BroadcastEvent\",\"command\":\"O:38:\\\"Illuminate\\\\Broadcasting\\\\BroadcastEvent\\\":4:{s:5:\\\"event\\\";O:28:\\\"App\\\\Events\\\\NewMarketSnapshot\\\":1: ...

Comment: Also, don't forget to clear any cached config with `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: Oh! That got it to broadcast finally! "php artisan config:clear" Solved. Thank you so much!

Comment: You are also right about not using redis driver for both queue and broadcast. I tried to switch back and it failed.

Comment: Glad it resolved the issue! If I recall correctly it should be using PUBLISH instead of RPUSH on broadcast now. I think you can still use Redis for both, but you have to set up separate connections, so it might be easier to switch your queue to something like Beanstalk.

Comment: This was my problem. After switching the queue driver in my .env or in config file queue.php from `database` to `sync` things worked like magic :)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue, everything was set up correctly even I tested pusher at the start and it was working OK. The problem was, I switch `QUEUE_CONNECTION` to `database` to use Laravel's queue system for sending email asynchronously. 
So the solution that worked for is to `implements ShouldBroadcastNow` for my event as 
 `class NewNotificationEvent implements ShouldBroadcastNow` and everything working OK again.